# How to pass controller's ModelState to my service constructor with Autofac?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I have a wrapper on ModelStateDictionary which all my services accept. Is it possible to configure the autofac to inject the controller ModelStateDictionary into the constructor of the wrapper and then inject it into service constructor?

```
//code
public class ModelValidation : IModelValidation { 
public ModelValidation(ModelStateDictionary msd){...}
..
..
}

public class CustomerService{
public CustomerService(IModelValidation mv){...}
..
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just updated my answer with a possibly interesting idea that will save you from declaring a bunch of factory delegates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on your comments I hereby revise my answer :)

`ModelStateDictionary` is clearly not a **service** that should be resolved by the container, but rather **data** that should be provided at instantiation time. We can tell that from the fact that ModelState is owned by each Controller instance and is thus not available to the container at "resolve time".

Furthermore, each `ModelValidation` instance will be bound to a `ModelStateDictionary` instance and is thus also to be considered as **data**.

In Autofac, when data must be passed to constructors (optionally in addition to other dependencies), we must use factory delegates. These delegates will handle dependency and data passing to the constructor. The sweet thing with Autofac is that these delegates can be autogenerated.

I propose the following solution:

Since both ModelValidation and CustomerService requires data in their constructors, we need two factory delegates (note: the parameter names must match the names in their corresponding constructor):

```
public delegate IModelValidation ModelValidationFactory(ModelStateDictionary msd);
public delegate CustomerService CustomerServiceFactory(ModelStateDictionary msd);
```

Since your controllers shouldn't know where these delegates comes from they should be passed to the controller constructor as dependencies:

```
public class EditCustomerController : Controller
{
    private readonly CustomerService _customerService;

    public EditCustomerController(CustomerServiceFactory customerServiceFactory
        /*, ...any other dependencies required by the controller */
          )
    {
        _customerService = customerServiceFactory(this.ModelState);
    }

}
```

The CustomerService should have a constructor similar to this (optionally handle some of this in a ServiceBase class):

```
public class CustomerService
{
    private readonly IModelValidation _modelValidation;

    public CustomerService(ModelStateDictionary msd,
              ModelValidationFactory modelValidationFactory)
    {
        _modelValidation = modelValidationFactory(msd);
    }
```

To make this happen we need to build our container like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Register<ModelValidation>().As<IModelValidation>().FactoryScoped();
builder.Register<CustomerService>().FactoryScoped();

builder.RegisterGeneratedFactory<ModelValidationFactory>();
builder.RegisterGeneratedFactory<CustomerServiceFactory>();

builder.Register<EditCustomerController>().FactoryScoped();
```

So, when the controller is resolved (eg when using [the MvcIntegration module](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration)), the factory delegates will be injected into the controllers and services.

**Update**: to cut down on required code even more, you could replace `CustomerServiceFactory` with a generic factory delegate like I've described [here](http://peterspattern.com/generate-generic-factories-with-autofac).

Comment: Container creates new ModelStateDictionary and passes it to ModelValidation constructor. I would like to pass existing ModelStateDictionary (which is accessible via Controller.ModelState property) to ModelValidation constructor. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you elaborate this in your question? is Controller.ModelState a static? or how is it declared today?

Comment: The Controller.ModelState is a property of ModelStateDictionary type. The controller is created by asp.net mvc runtime (controller factory), and the ModelStateDictionary is created there. Then I can create my controllers by subclassing the controller and I'm able to access the ModelState property in my class. If I'm unclear, please let me know and I'll repost my question in greater detail.

Comment: Thanks Peter, As far as I understood your answer, this approach requires 2 LOC in every controller's constructor to handle this. This is ..well I would like to avoid it and have Autofac handle this for me. Currently I'm just passing the ModelStateDictionary to my service with one line of code: every service interface inherits from base interface with has a settable property that accepts the ModelStateDictionary, so I'm able to simply assign the ModelStateDictionary to the service interface property with 1 LOC.

Comment: Ok, with that in mind I was able to simplify the controller down to 1 LOC. You will still need the factory delegates in order to pass the dictionary into the service and validation instances.

Comment: clarifying data vs service is a great way to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Builder.RegisterInstance(new ModelStateDictionary()).SingleInstance();
            builder.Register(c => new SW.PL.Util.ModelStateWrapper
(c.Resolve<ModelStateDictionary>())).As<IValidationDictionary>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Comment: Can you add as single instance

Comment: This question is a long time no longer actual, sorry. I don't even program .NET anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a new constructor without ValidationService. Assign the ValidationService by using a property.

The property must be implemented in the interface ICostumerService

```
public class ModelStateWrapper: IValidationDictionary {  
public ModelStateWrapper(ModelStateDictionary msd){}
}

public class CustomerService: ICostumerService{
public IValidationDictionary ValidationDictionary { get; set; }
public CustomerService(ICustomerRepsitory customerRepository, IValidationDictionary validationDictionary ){} 
public CustomerService(ICustomerRepsitory customerRepository){}
}

public Controller(ICustomerService customerService)
{
  _customerService= menuService;
  _customerService.ValidationDictionary = new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState);
  _customerService= sportsService;
}
```